# What does "Open-N-Use" mean?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting, softbox, umbrella

In the description of a softbox kit it says "Open-N-Use as studio umbrella. More convenient than traditional soft box." What does that mean exactly?

Here's the product
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Photography-Photo-Studio-Softbox-Continuous-Video-Light-Lighting-Kit-VL-9099-/120804387578?pt=AU_Cameras_Photographic_Accessories&hash=item1c2080aafa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open-n-use has a similar meaning to the much more common "plug-n-play" adjective of computer peripherals, it means you just open it up like an umbrella and start using it right away.

Essentially it's an umbrella softbox hybrid that opens quickly like an umbrella, but has a front diffuser screen like a softbox, giving a softbox like quality of light but without the hassle of assembling a softbox (which can be like putting up a small tent at times).